# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence.<init>(Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodableVector;)V

Tags: java, timestamp, runtime-error, bouncycastle

I've got an error when I try to get a TimeStamp response. The piece of code that I use is:

```
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(pk, chain, null, "SHA256", null, false);
        InputStream data = sap.getRangeStream();
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256",
                "BC");
        byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
        int n;
        while ((n = data.read(buf)) > 0) {
            messageDigest.update(buf, 0, n);
        }
        byte hash[] = messageDigest.digest();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        byte[] ocsp = null;

        byte sh[] = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, ocsp);
        sgn.update(sh, 0, sh.length);
        byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, tsc, ocsp);
        System.out.println("contentEstimated: " + (contentEstimated + 2));
        System.out.println("encodedSig.length: " + encodedSig.length);
```

The error appears on the line:
    byte sh[] = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, ocsp);

The error is:

```
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: Exception in Transaction.
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:404)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:227)
        at org.alfresco.web.bean.dialog.BaseDialogBean.finish(BaseDialogBean.java:127)
        at org.alfresco.web.bean.dialog.DialogManager.finish(DialogManager.java:534)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:132)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:70)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence.<init>(Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodableVector;)V
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.getAuthenticatedAttributeSet(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.module.veritasCONTRATOS.model.service.EmisionContratoServiceImpl.firmaDocumentoTimestamp(EmisionContratoServiceImpl.java:366)
        at org.alfresco.module.veritasCONTRATOS.model.service.EmisionContratoServiceImpl.firmaContrato(EmisionContratoServiceImpl.java:164)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:296)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.firmaContrato(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.module.veritasCONTRATOS.beans.AddEmConDialog.finishImpl(AddEmConDialog.java:111)
        at org.alfresco.web.bean.dialog.BaseDialogBean$1.execute(BaseDialogBean.java:121)
        at org.alfresco.web.bean.dialog.BaseDialogBean$1.execute(BaseDialogBean.java:118)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:320)
        ... 31 more
```

I show same errors like this (http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Nosuchmethod-error-for-bouncy-castle-td3492864.html), but i can't do this working. 
I know that the problem is with bouncycastle libaries. I try with this versions:

- bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar
- bcmail-jdk15-1.46.jar
- itextpdf-5.1.2.jar

And other verios of bcprov-jdk (16-146, 14-146, 15-137, 15-1.43).

Anyone know what i am doin wrong??
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible jars in your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your time.

I solved this issue replacing bcprov-jdk, bcmail-jdk and bctsp-jdk versions 15-146 to 15-143 version.